# Android: ImageView src ignores the layout_weight property of parent element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two vertical table rows with the property `layout_weight = "1"` so they take equal space vertically, but if I add an "ImageView" tag in those tables tags with `android:src` property it resizes the parent tableRow tag according to the image's real size, so is there any way that I can keep those equal heights of `TableRow` without specifying the exact size of ImageView or TableRow
Code,

working code (simplified version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

But as soon as I add the `android:src` to ImageViews property and choose an image, the size of the parent `<TableRow>` changes according to the size of that image, is there any way that the image just fits into the current size of the parent `and doesn't change its parent size?

based on Manishika answer I tried this code but it didn't work either

```
<TableLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight=".5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note: For better performance and tooling support, you should instead build your layout with ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the need for my current project @SimpleCoder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the parent_layout has a `android:weightSum="2"`  attribute

> android:weightSum
>
> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can
>   be used for instance to give a single child 50% of the total available
>   space by giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to
>   1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This way both the rows will divide the table layout height.
Height i specified as 400dp just to test if its getting divided equally among the rows. You can keep it match parent or anything depending upon your requirement.

```
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp">
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the scale type method. Furthermore, if you don't want your images to jump the rest of the layout you can always put a specific height or width

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `android:weightSum="2"` on your TableLayout, and you also need to set your `layout_width="0dp"` in both TableRow's. I don't think you need `android:layout_weight="1"` on your ImageView tho

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for answer, Please consider doing the below changes :

1. Add `android:measureWithLargestChild="true"` to your `TableLayout`, this will ensure to take row height of the largest height `TableRow` among all.
2. Instead of adding gravity to `TableLayout` add it to TableRows as `layout_gravity` controls how the view lays out its contents inside its own container and I believe you want the Images to be in center.
3. Add `weightSum` to `TableLayout` and divide the weights in each `TableRow`.

Try the below layout XML I used and is working :

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:weightSum="1"
             android:measureWithLargestChild="true">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight=".5">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for responding but it doesn't work, try adding more rows, for ex, add 10 tableRows (so `android:weightSum="10"` )and then add "src" property to random imageViews, you will see their container `<TableRows>` height changes

Comment: It does works with my changes even with 10 rows. Can you post the XML with my changes implemented

Comment: hi, you are using a small image `@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp` if you use a custom image which is of the bigger size it will extend the size of the container, pls try adding `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"`

Comment: I can't able to paste the full xml here, it exceeds words limit

Comment: I pasted XML in the question with your suggested changes